# How to develop Eclipse GUI plugins

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to develop a GUI plugin inside Eclipse such that I can expose a set of tasks and the user can drag-drop the tasks in the editor canvas and create connections between them like a workflow. A -> B -> C. In the background this would generate a set of Java classes with custom code.
Any pointers to what resources do I have for such a plugin ?

Answer (score 4):

Besides the basic SWT/Eclipse references given by Stephen, you could look into [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/) for the graphical part, perhaps in its combination with [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) in [GMP](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/). For generating the target code, you could look into [Jet](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html) or [Xpand](http://www.openarchitectureware.org/pub/documentation/4.3/html/contents/xtext_tutorial.html#d0e1893).

Comment: In case of GEF, I can show a graphical representation of a model. I want the other way around. I should be able to generate model based on what we drag and drop on the IDE.

Comment: @Ved That is exactly what GEF is about. The terminology might be a little confusing, since you do need a model of what you want to edit, but you create and edit instances of that model with a GEF editor. Check out the resources at http://www.eclipse.org/gef/reference/articles.html

Answer (score 1):

These books are a good place to start:

- [Eclipse Plug-ins (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462) by Eric Clayberg and Dan Rubel
- [SWT/JFace in Action: GUI Design with Eclipse 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394273) (In Action series) by Matthew Scarpino, Stephen Holder, Stanford Ng, and Laurent Mihalkovic

And of course, there's the [Eclipse documentation](http://eclipse.org/documentation/).