# Developing a GUI as an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I know there is a very similar topic to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590623/how-to-develop-eclipse-gui-plugins) but I have looked at the answers posted for it and I feel my problem is slightly different and doesn't need the same approach.

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin which is in essence a GUI that provides the user with different menus, buttons, editing areas etc. It's designed to be an all in one tool to help with coding, re-using code and re-structuring it.

I need a few pointers towards the resources available that can help me build this GUI and have it available as a plugin so I can get the ball rolling. I've looked at the suggestions in the link above but I don't feel like my plugin needs for example a model, view, controller design pattern. I just need the ability to have a GUI pop up when the user starts the plugin and have them interact with it.

Any suggestions or ideas are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GUI has to be an multi-page editor.  One (or more) page(s) for the GUI, and one page for the code.

Use the "Plug-in with a multi-page editor" template to get started.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590668/300257) should help you fill out your template code.

When you have a specific question, feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Tutorials at [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html) especially the [Eclipse plugin section](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html). Those tutorials are usually very good. I learned Eclipse RCP with it.